# Why loading model which has a byte array field by hibernate gets null value?

Tags: java, hibernate, arrays, lob

A pojo for hibernate, which has a `Lob` field, and it's type is `byte[]`:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import static javax.persistence.AccessType.FIELD;

@Entity
@Access(FIELD)
@Table(name = "MYFILE")
public class MyFile implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "MYSEQ", sequenceName = "MYSEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MYSEQ")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "FILE_CONTENT")
    @Lob
    private byte[] fileContent;

    // getters and setters

}
```

Then I read an empty file and save it to database:

```
MyFile file = new MyFile();
file.setFileContent(new byte[0]);

sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(file);
```

I want to load it in another transaction:

```
MyFile myFile = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().query("...").uniqueResult();
System.out.println(myFile.fileContent);
```

It prints:

```
null
```

I don't understand why the field `fileContent` is `null`, should not it be `new byte[0]`?

Comment: Have you tried @Lob@Basic(fetch=EAGER).

Comment: Have you tried with a non-empty byte array?

Comment: @JBNizet, non-empty byte array is working well. Will get a byte array with correct content when loading.

Comment: Isn't that simply a "feature" of your database? Oracle, for example, will actually save NULL in a varchar column when you save an empty string. I wouldn't be surprised if the behavior was the same with an ampty byte array in a blob column.

Comment: I don't think that any database can differentiate between an empty byte[] and null.  They both contain nothing. The empty byte[] just provides a reference to memory in RAM that can contain some information.  The column in the database table provides the same function.  They are both just containers.  When you query the table you are getting the contents of the column. (null)